# kendo MVC wrapper grid. How do i specify the data type of a nested model field?

Tags: model-view-controller, kendo-ui, grid

I have a project work work with hundreds of grids.  On one grid in particular, the original designer created a view and added it as a nested model inside our driver model.  This is a problem because Kendo seems to not be able to detect the field type of a field nested this way. When it can't, it assumes the field is a string.

In my particular case, I have two fields that contain dates that we want to filter on, but the date filtering is broken because of this.

I was able to find numerous examples of specifying it in the data source, but only for jquery grids (one example:  https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/knowledge-base/use-nested-model-properties ).  I can't convert this to mvc because the methods aren't lining up.

Any idea on how to do this in mvc?  Note:  I also tried just changing the UI on the filter to date and that didn't work either.  I got a stack trace claiming date needed to be a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, according to Telerik , the fact is that you simply can't do what I was trying to do.  The solution is to flatten the model.  I pulled the questionable fields into notmapped fields in the master model.
The relevant part of their response:

> In MVC the nested properties are properties to another Model. As the Telerik UI Grid needs a flat structure of data, the nested properties could be shown with the help of a ClientTemplate, but they will always be string typed.
> In order to achieve the desired behavior, I would recommend making the pointed Date fields - part of the Main Model and using them as flat data out of the box.

Link:  https://www.telerik.com/forums/kendo-mvc-wrapper-grid-how-do-i-specify-the-data-type-of-a-nested-model-field

The caveat here is you can't filter a linq-for-queries datasource to a notmapped field because it doesn't exist in it but in my case, a .toList() didn't cause any performance problems because the dataset was small, with only a few hundred records.
However, you can edit the incoming DatasourceRequest object to modify the filters and sorts to point at the sub model, after your controller read is hit.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand the model passed to the Grid's field is structured like this:

```
public class OrderViewModel
{
    public int OrderID
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public CityModel ShipCity
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

public class CityModel
{
    public int CityID 
    { 
         get; 
         set;
    };

    public string CityName 
    { 
         get;
         set;
    };

}
```

Then you can utilize the [ClientTemplate configuration](https://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-core/api/Kendo.Mvc.UI.Fluent/GridBoundColumnBuilder#clienttemplatesystemstring) to get the CityName to populate the column:

```
columns.Bound(p => p.ShipCity).ClientTemplate("#=ShipCity.CityName#");
```

For more information refer to the [Kendo UI Templates article](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/templates/overview)
or
this forum answer that shows [how to set a default to a nested field in a Grid's DataSource Model configuration](https://www.telerik.com/forums/grid-updates-using-nested-child-objects#2836951).

Comment: that doesn't translate properly into the row filter.  You'll end up bound to the object so you won't be able to filter at all.